# Uploading images on server via PHP - files don't get sent to assigned folder

Tags: php, upload

**Goal:** My plan is to **upload images on a folder via PHP.**

**Problem:** The images I upload **don't show up in the upload-folder.** No errors appear during uploading. It's stating that the upload was successful.

**Code**

**form**

```
<form action='upload.php' method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
<input type='file' name='file'>
<button type='submit' name='submit'>Upload</button>
</form>"
```

**upload.php** - the Script for uploading and moving the image-file to the uploads-folder

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $file = $_FILES['file'];

    $fileName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $fileTmpName = $_FILES['file']['tmp name'];
    $fileSize = $_FILES['file']['size'];
    $fileError = $_FILES['file']['error'];
    $fileType = $_FILES['file']['type'];

    $fileExt = explode('.', $fileName);
    $fileActualExt = strtolower(end($fileExt));

    $allowed = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png');

    if (in_array($fileActualExt, $allowed)) {
        if ($fileError === 0) {
            if ($fileSize < 500000) {
                $fileNameNew = uniqid('', true).'.'.$fileActualExt;
                $fileDestination = 'uploads/'.$fileNameNew;
                move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName, $fileDestination);
                header('Location: index.php?uploadsuccess');
            } else {
                echo 'File too big!';
            }
        } else {
            echo 'Error whrend Uploads.';

        }
    } else {
        echo 'Falscher Dateityp.';
    }
}
```

The header-information header('Location: index.php?uploadsuccess') comes through when I try to upload a picture. The uploads folder is directly located in the root folder with the other files. I'm using Xampp. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL);` atop

Comment: @mario If you look long enough, you'll see it's a typo. Took me a minute or two but there is one and was quite elusive/masked. A probable silent fail and a very odd one at that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it.

```
    $fileTmpName = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
```

A sneaky, missing underscore.

Comment: Yep! Just like I told Mario up there. One silly "off-topic" typo.